# Trying to Override JS Timer

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JS - I've looked for different solutions on how to override a button timer but haven't found any solutions that worked for this application. I'm not even sure if I'm looking in the right place.

```
jQuery.timers = [];
jQuery.fx.tick = function() {
    var timer,
        i = 0,
        timers = jQuery.timers;

    fxNow = Date.now();

    for ( ; i < timers.length; i++ ) {
        timer = timers[ i ];

        // Run the timer and safely remove it when done (allowing for external removal)
        if ( !timer() && timers[ i ] === timer ) {
            timers.splice( i--, 1 );
        }
    }

    if ( !timers.length ) {
        jQuery.fx.stop();
    }
    fxNow = undefined;
};

jQuery.fx.timer = function( timer ) {
    jQuery.timers.push( timer );
    jQuery.fx.start();
};

jQuery.fx.interval = 13;
jQuery.fx.start = function() {
    if ( inProgress ) {
        return;
    }

    inProgress = true;
    schedule();
};

jQuery.fx.stop = function() {
    inProgress = null;
};

jQuery.fx.speeds = {
    slow: 600,
    fast: 200,

    // Default speed
    _default: 400
};
```

This is what I'm looking at in the sources - is this even the right place? If so, what could I enter into the console to override?

Comment: What do you mean by override the timer?

Comment: I don't see a timer anywhere in that code. Maybe it's in`schedule()`?

Comment: You should be able to modify the `jQuery.timers` array.

Comment: You should explain what you want to do instead of what you are looking at in the jQuery sources... And if you cannot explain your objective, I would recommand you do not modify any library source.